# Abstruct __construct in Abstract class. declaration must be compatible...Error of the PHP?

Tags: php

It is works!

```
abstract class Base
{
    public function __construct(int $a)
    {
        
    }
}

class Extend extends Base
{
    function __construct(int $a, $b)
    {
        parent::__construct($a);
    }
}


$extended2 = new Extend(1, 2);
```

It is not works! Gives an error message. Fatal error:  Declaration of Extend::__construct(int $a, $b) must be compatible with Base::__construct(int $a)

```
abstract class Base
{
    abstract public function __construct(int $a);
}

class Extend extends Base
{
    function __construct(int $a, $b)
    {
        parent::__construct($a);
    }
}


$extended2 = new Extend(1, 2);
```

Comment: In the first case the constructor in `Base` acts as a constructor of a parent class. In the second case the constructor of `Base` acts as an interface method. You can add more arguments to a method of a parent class, but you can't on interface methods. So this works as intended.

Comment: @PtrTon Where is it in the documentation ?

Comment: While I had been taking what @PtrTon wrote as a given, I can't find the support for that claim in the docs. It seems as though it's not outright stated there. The [signature compatibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop.lsp) section even states that _"The constructor, and private methods are exempt from these signature compatibility rules, and thus won't emit a fatal error in case of a signature mismatch."_, which could be a source of confusion.